# Convert JSON to a table and attatch it to a body of an email in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to convert a JSON Object to a table and attatch it to the body of an email.

**index.js**

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    port: 587, // SMTP PORT
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
        user: process.env.USER,
        pass: process.env.PASSWORD
    }
});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const done = (err, res) => callback(null, {
        statusCode: err ? '400' : '200',
        body: err ? err.message : JSON.stringify(res),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST'
        },
    });
    
    //context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    
    let obj = event.Records[0];

    
    let _body = JSON.stringify(obj);
    


    let mailOptions = {
        from: 'abc@xyz.io',
        to: '123@xyz.io',
        subject: 'Alert: There is change to site sftp data (add, update, delete)',
        html: _body
    };

    console.log("Email send");
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, done(null, _body));
};
```

The `Records[0]` above is a JSON Object which looks like this:

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "EventSource": "aws:sns",
      "EventVersion": "1.0",
      "EventSubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:{{{accountId}}}:ExampleTopic",
      "Sns": {
        "Type": "Notification",
        "MessageId": "95df01b4-ee98-5cb9-9903-4c221d41eb5e",
        "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:ExampleTopic",
        "Subject": "example subject",
        "Message": "example message",
        "Timestamp": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "SignatureVersion": "1",
        "Signature": "EXAMPLE",
        "SigningCertUrl": "EXAMPLE",
        "UnsubscribeUrl": "EXAMPLE",
        "MessageAttributes": {
          "Test": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Value": "TestString"
          },
          "TestBinary": {
            "Type": "Binary",
            "Value": "TestBinary"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to convert this JSON to a table format and attach it to the body of the email, which looks something like this:

```
|---------------------|--------------------------------------------------|
|    EventSource      |                     aws:sns                      |
|---------------------|--------------------------------------------------|
|    EventVersion     |                      1.0                         |
|---------------------|--------------------------------------------------|
|EventSubscriptionArn |arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:{{{accountId}}}:ExampleTopic|
|---------------------|--------------------------------------------------|
|       Sns           |                                                  |
|---------------------|--------------------------------------------------|
|       Type          |         Notification                             |
|---------------------|--------------------------------------------------|
|    MessageId        |         95df01b4-ee98-5cb9-9903-4c221d41eb5e     |
|---------------------|--------------------------------------------------|
|    TopicArn         | arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:ExampleTopic  |
|---------------------|--------------------------------------------------|
...
...
... So on
```

May I please know if there is a best possible way to achieve this with javascript?

Comment: You can use npm modules like this one. https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-table-converter . Just google json to table and you'll get the available options. Thanks!

Comment: You can use [ejs templates](https://ejs.co/) to insert json into your desired templates